# Can not restart mysql service after getting Error 2002 Can't connect to local mysql server

Tags: mysql

Starting yesterday, I'm getting this error when connecting to mysql:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I haven't touched my setup for ~1 month so I don't believe its driven by any changes I've attempted to make to the setup. When I try to restart mysql service with

```
service mysqld restart
```

I get this error:

```
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Operation not permitted
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
```

And if I try:

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

I just get:

```
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I think its a permissions issue based off what I've read on other server fault threads about the same error but I'm still stumped because I should have permissions to execute files in that directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 mysql mysql 4096 Jun 21 16:42 /var/lib/mysql
```

Update: logs below. Looks like a memory issue but I don't know how to address:

```
140618 20:17:46 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140618 20:17:46 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140618 20:17:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140618 20:17:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140618 20:17:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140618 20:17:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140618 20:17:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140618 20:17:47 [ERROR] Aborting

140618 20:17:47 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140618 20:17:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140621 16:42:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140621 16:42:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140621 16:42:49 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140621 16:42:49 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140621 16:42:49 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140621 16:42:49 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140621 16:42:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140621 16:42:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140621 16:42:50 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140621 16:42:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140621 16:42:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140621 16:42:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140621 16:42:50 [ERROR] Aborting

140621 16:42:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140621 16:42:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

UPDATE: Found the answer here which was setting up a swap file. The full details I followed on how to do this can be found here: http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html

Comment: The first half of the question is simply because you are not root. For the second half, can you see if there are any logs generated in  /var/log/ with more verbose details? Right now it could be many things.

Comment: @DavidHoude posted logs, looks like a memory issue but don't know how to fix

Comment: The log shows that MySQL started at 2:53, and was shut down at 20:03, that is, 17 hours 10 minutes after start-up. When did you execute the `sudo service mysqld restart` command?

Comment: Those logs show a normal shutdown, you need to show us the part relevant to the failed startup.

Comment: @lain - My bad, thought I'd pasted that in first time (updated logs above)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure all mysql files are owned by the mysql user. Verify that the mysql log files are owned by the MySQL User.

```
ls -l /var/log/mysql*
```

If not set the proper owner:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql....
```

Do the same for all directories listed in your my.cnf:

```
root# grep mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir = /data/mysql
log_bin=/data/mysql/binlogs/mysql-bin.log
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql_slow_query.log
log-error=/var/log/mysql_error.log
innodb_data_home_dir = /data/mysql
```

For directories use recursive chown:

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /data/mysql
```

Comment: do chown commands as root or via sudo ... carefully